# How to store user input in variable that is a different value than in the variable initialization in default constructor?

Tags: c++, class, object, constructor, default-constructor

Sorry for the lengthy title of this post. However, I believe it sums up the issue I am having. I have a default constructor that sets these defaults every time an object gets called:

```
Circles::Circles()
{
   radius = 1;
   center_x = 0;
   center_y = 0;
}
```

However, I want to give the user the option enter their own values. This would mean that the default values of `radius`, `center_x` and `center_y` must be ignored somehow. I set up the prompt like this:

```
char enter;    // for user selection
    float rad = 1; // for user selection
    int x = 0, y = 0;     // for user selection

    cout << "Would you like to enter a radius for sphere2? (Y/N): ";
    cin.get(enter);

    if (toupper(enter) != 'N')
    {
        cout << "Please enter a radius: ";
        cin >> rad;
    }

    cout << endl;

    cout << "Would you like to enter a center for sphere2? (Y/N): ";
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore();
    cin.get(enter);

    if (toupper(enter) != 'N')
    {
        cout << "Please enter x: ";
        cin >> x;
        cout << "Please enter y: ";
        cin >> y;
    }

    cout << endl << endl;

    if (toupper(enter) == 'Y')
        Circles sphere2(rad, x, y);
   Circles sphere2;
```

I want to pass `rad`, `x`, and `y` to this overloaded constructor:

```
Circles::Circles(float r, int x, int y)
{
   radius = r;
   center_x = x;
   center_y = y;
}
```

This is how the output gets sent to the screen:

```
cout << "Sphere2:\n";
cout << "The radius of the circle is " << radius << endl;
cout << "The center of the circle is (" << center_x 
    << "," << center_y << ")" << endl;
```

At last, we arrive at the problem that the default values get printed:

> The radius of the circle is 1 The center of the circle is (0,0)

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (toupper(enter) == 'Y')
        Circles sphere2(rad, x, y);
   Circles sphere2;
```

It creates local variable `sphere2` at two different scopes (as if into two different functions). One at function scope, another at if-block scope. They are different. If-block variable will cease to exist (destruct) as soon as if-block is executed.

Work with only one instance variable. You need to provide functions to `Set` the values. For example

```
Circles sphere;
sphere.SetX(x);
sphere.SetY(y);
```

The methods `SetX` and `SetY` will (should) set member-variable values of any already constructed instance.

Comment: Great! Thanks. I've always wondered why nobody creates objects inside different scopes as if it were a more dynamic process.

Comment: You can. If you use dynamic allocation. Either by allocating memory yourself, or using smart pointers.